# How to set Kafka Producer message rate per second?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am reading a csv file and giving the rows of this input to my Kafka Producer. now I want my Kafka Producer to produce messages at a rate of 100 messages per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `linger.ms` and  `batch.size` properties of Kafka Producer. 
You have to adjust these properties correspondingly to get desired rate.

> The producer groups together any records that arrive in between request transmissions into a single batched request. Normally this occurs only under load when records arrive faster than they can be sent out. However in some circumstances the client may want to reduce the number of requests even under moderate load. This setting accomplishes this by adding a small amount of artificial delay—that is, rather than immediately sending out a record the producer will wait for up to the given delay to allow other records to be sent so that the sends can be batched together. This can be thought of as analogous to Nagle's algorithm in TCP. This setting gives the upper bound on the delay for batching: once we get batch.size worth of records for a partition it will be sent immediately regardless of this setting, however if we have fewer than this many bytes accumulated for this partition we will 'linger' for the specified time waiting for more records to show up. This setting defaults to 0 (i.e. no delay). Setting linger.ms=5, for example, would have the effect of reducing the number of requests sent but would add up to 5ms of latency to records sent in the absense of load.

Answer (score 0):

If you like stream processing then akka-streams has nice support for throttling: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/stream/stream-quickstart.html#time-based-processing

Then the akka-stream-kafka (aka reactive-kafka) library allows you to connect the two together: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka JVM Producer, the throughput depends upon multiple factors. And most commonly it's calculated in MB/sec rather than Msg/sec. In your example, if let's say each of your row in CSV is 1MB in size then you need to tune your producer configs to achieve 100MB/sec, so that you can achieve your target throughput of 100 Msg/sec. While tuning producer configs, you have to take into the consideration what's your `batch.size` ( measured in bytes ) config value? If it's set too low then producer will try to send messages more often and wait for reply from server. This will improve the producer's throughput. But would impact the latency. If you are using async callback based producer then in this case your overall throughput will be limited by how many number of messages producer can send before waiting for reply from server determined by `max.in.flight.request.per.connection`. 
If you keep `batch.size` too high then producer throughput will get affected since after waiting for `linger.ms` period kafka producer will send the all messages in a batch to broker for that particular partition at once. But having bigger `batch.size` means bigger `buffer.memory` which might put pressure on GC.